# Browserify by Grunt.js watch

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, browserify

I'm new to [Grunt.js](https://gruntjs.com).

Until now, I have been running

`browserify ./js/app.js -o ./js/app.bundle.js`

on every file change-saved.

Now, I'm trying to automate this process with Grunt(0.4.2) watch.

What is the proper manner to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to use grunt to run that same browserify compilation in grunt watch task?

If you have something written to your Gruntfile.js already, it would help if you could share that somewhere as a template.

Comment: Thanks. No Gruntfile.js file yet. I've just seen some sample template. I would appreciate if you give me the one to automate the browserify on the file saving.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd set up watch task with [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) that launches browserify build via [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) when source files change.

To put it in action, here is a sample Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
      files: ['app/app.js'],
      tasks: ['browserify']
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'app/app.bundle.js': ['app/app.js'],
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
};
```

Now you can just use it to watch for changes by invoking:

```
grunt watch
```

Note that you need to have grunt along with `grunt-contrib-watch` and `grunt-browserify`installed.

---

Alternatively you could consider using Gulp instead of Grunt. Similar result can be achieved with [gulp-browserify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-browserify) along with [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch) with less verbose build file and some potential performance gains.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've checked this one. One thing I thought I should be careful is the last update is 9month ago, and it printed `dependncy out of date`. Is this method comapatible the latest  Grunt(0.4.2)?

Comment: You are probably right on the fact that grunt-watchify is somewhat out of date (it reports to work with grunt `~0.4.0` though so it should work). How about `grunt-contrib-watch` along with `grunt-browserify`? You probably can use them together to end up with same result.

Comment: Thanks, I also have checked `grunt-browserify` and would use it with `grunt-contrib-watch`. It's one of my motivation to ask this question how to write the `Gruntfile.js` for it. Can you show me the proper way.

Comment: Got it. Added a sample file.

Comment: jsalonen, thank you very much for your sample code. Referring it, my first grunt project works as intended. Appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm late, but I'm using browserify with grunt via `grunt-browserify`. It has a very handy option `watch: true` that uses watchify instead of browserify and speeds up largely the task.

My Gruntfile.js looks like:

```
browserify: {
  dev: {
    src: ['./lib/app.js'],
    dest: 'build/bundle.<%= pkg.name %>.js',
    options: {
      transform: ['reactify'],
      watch: true
    }
   }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['browserify:dev']);
```

Of course I had to install watchify with npm before.